# PK / UK index in Oracle SQL DEVELOPER example HR user

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

On Oracles sql database 11g I've got example DB. I understand everything except what means that PK/UK index (I know what this shortcuts stand for) and why every relation included in schema got there : "country_c_id_pk" from some child side table. 
What is for this field, where every relation of DB has the same data in it ?
First picture shows whole table and others the properties of some relations.

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxGS0.jpg` : general view

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9AvS.png`

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/B51Xs.png`

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL1qa.png`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you know what does PK mean and what does UK mean. Next question - how database maintains these constraints.

If you have a table with 1'000'000'000 records and you wish to insert yet another one, it's quite sad to scan it all from start to finish and check 'is there equal id here?'. It's very sad to do this. Instead of it, when anybody creates PK or UK, database check if table has index on these columns. If index exists - database uses it to check existance of IDs. If appropriate index not found - database creates it automatically.

This attribute shows which index would be used.

Next question is why all tables have equal values here. I guess it's just a bug. One of a million SQLDeveloper bugs. If you wish to know truth, execute this:

```
select
  t.TABLE_NAME,
  c.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
  c.INDEX_NAME
from
  user_tables t,
  user_constraints c
where
  t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME and
  c.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P'
```

In most cases constraint name and index name are the same, it means auto-created index. But in some cases developer makes index first, then constraint uses this index, and if developer named both of them, names can be differenct.